# Не запускается скомпилированный jar файл через двойное нажатие

Tags: java, jar

Использую IDEA.
Проект maven.
Сокпмилил jar файл с MANIFEST, все как нужно.

Запускаться двойным кликом не хочет, через cmd(`java -jar jarFile.jar`) - окей.
В чем может быть проблема?

Если запускаю двойным кликом то на секунду появляется командная строка и пропадает.
Пробовал выбирать "Открыть с помощью" и java.exe и javaw.exe  - не помогает.

Я сделал батник, но хотелось бы без него.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что запускать `jar` файлы можно только командой `java -jar file.jar`. Потому что `java` принимает на вход и оперирует не только с `jar` файлами. Имитировать запуск двойной кнопкой можно создав батник с нужной командой, и запуская даблкликом его. Или через реестр вносить правки ([пример на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30571306/7519767)).

`.jar` не является исполняемым файлом Windows, его могут запускать определённые программы, но этого не всегда достаточно для даблклик-запуска.

К тому же, далеко не всегда `jar`ник кроме вывода в консоль будет делать что-то ещё, и эту консоль придётся запускать либо вам вручную, запуская батник, либо окольными путями, меняя что-то в реестре.

Comment: я все джарники, что качал, запускал двойным кликом, наверное все-таки можно. Приходилось через консоль только тогда, когда в main нужно значения передавать

Comment: @Maxgmer если честно, первый раз слышу, что джарники запускают даблкликом. Вы уверены, что то были именно джарники? Можете пример скинуть?

Comment: У вас наверно просто jar а не executable jar. Попробуйте запустить свой командой `java -jar file.jar` и напишите результат.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin сюда наверное нельзя кидать, можете сами скачать https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server. Пишут, что требует аргументы в main, но и без них запустится

Comment: @Maxgmer почитайте текст на странице, ссылку на которую вы скинули. Там же команда для запуска прямо в центре.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin это необязательная конфигурация, только что даже сам скачал и перепроверил. Скачайте и посмотрите, вам сгенерирует файлы сервера

Comment: @PeterSamokhin нашел ответ в интернете, можно при установке jre "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program" для .java. А вообще, я не помню, чтобы я такое отмечал вручную, возможно jre уже автоматически так ставится

Comment: @PeterSamokhin можно запускать jar дабл кликом. Сам такое делал. И как-то уже делал запускаемый jar в идее, но забыл в чем была проблема.